# Concavity of Spectral mean

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

The geometric mean of two positive definite matrices $A, B$ is defined by $A\sharp B=A^{1/2}(A^{-1/2}BA^{-1/2})^{1/2}A^{1/2}$. The following inequality holds true $$\left(\sum_{i=1}^n A_i\right)\sharp \left(\sum_{i=1}^n B_i\right)\ge\sum_{i=1}^n A_i\sharp B_i$$ for positive definite matrices $A_i, B_i$, $i=1\ldots, n$.

The spectral mean is defined by Fiedler and Ptak as 
$A\natural B=(A^{-1}\sharp B)^{1/2}A(A^{-1}\sharp B)^{1/2}$. Is the spectral mean also concave? That is, whether

$$\left(\sum_{i=1}^n A_i\right)\natural \left(\sum_{i=1}^n B_i\right)\ge\sum_{i=1}^n A_i\natural B_i$$ for positive definite matrices $A_i, B_i$, $i=1\ldots, n$?

The inequality here is Loewner order.

Comment: I'd consider changing the notation. The two symbols are too easily confused.

Comment: These notation is standard, see e.g. Volume 1, Number 3 (2007), 443–447 of Journal of
Mathematical
Inequalities.

Comment: I know it's standard; I just think it's no good... :(

Comment: @Suvrit, I deleted that confusing words.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some experiments reveal that the said inequality **does not** hold for the spectral mean.

Here is a random (i.e., mindless) counterexample:

\begin{equation*}
 A_1=\begin{bmatrix}
 29 & 15\\\\
 15 & 26
\end{bmatrix},\quad A_2=\begin{bmatrix}
5 & 0\\\\
0 & 5
\end{bmatrix},\quad B_1=\begin{bmatrix}
4 & -16\\\\
-16 & 113
\end{bmatrix},\quad B_2=\begin{bmatrix}
18 & -12\\\\
-12 & 16
\end{bmatrix}.
\end{equation*}

With this choice, we have

\begin{equation*}
 (A_1+A_2)\natural (B_1+B_2) = \begin{bmatrix}
 22.3606 & 0.4475\\\\
 0.4475 & 58.3661
\end{bmatrix},\quad (A_1\natural B_1)+(A_2\natural B_2) =\begin{bmatrix}
15.2404 & -2.2975\\\\
-2.2975 & 58.5164
\end{bmatrix}.
\end{equation*}

A quick calculation shows that the difference between the two matrices is an indefinite matrix, so the alleged inequality does not hold.

Comment: @Betrand: For the above example, I used trivial matlab code using eigendecomposition. But for more accurate evaluation, or larger matrices, I tend to use Bruno's matrix means toolbox: http://bezout.dm.unipi.it/software/mmtoolbox/